# how to make multi criteria query in Yii?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii

I want to make a query that can have more than one critera, as the following:

`select * from table where c1 IN(...) AND c2 IN (....) AND c3 IN (....);`

I may be use the 3 fields (c1..c3) or may be use one field only, and the arrays of IN clauses are not fixed too, here is my code:

```
$w = 'select * from jobs where ';
                        $c1 = new CDbCriteria();
                        if($dcr!=null){
                            $w = $w.'division IN(';
                            $dcrr = "'". implode("', '", $dcr) ."'";
                            $w  = $w.$dcrr.");";
                            foreach($dcr as $txt){ 
                                $c1->compare('division',$txt,true,'OR');
                            }
                        }

                        if($lcr!=null){
                            $c2 = new CDbCriteria();
                            foreach($lcr as $txt){ 
                               $c2->compare('location',$txt,true,'OR');
                            }
                        }

                        if($scr!=null){
                            $c3 = new CDbCriteria();
                           foreach($lcr as $txt){ 
                               $c3->compare('Salary',$txt,true,'OR');
                           }
                        }
                        $connection=Yii::app()->db;
                        $connection->active=true;
                        $command=$connection->createCommand($w);
                        $model = $command->query();
                        $connection->active=false;

                        $w='';
                    //$model = Jobs::model()->findAll($c2);
                    } 
                }



            $this->renderPartial('_index', array('model'=>$model));
```

Comment: Check this yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/quickstart.first-app and learn about using Yii right. Check the MVC Pattern and almost GII! Sorry, but your codes are not Yii conform.

Comment: @lin i know how to use Yii, this code is not working, I edited it many times and then copied it without removing the attributes before the update, my question just how to make a query with multi criteria in CDBCONNECTION, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to use [addInCondition](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addInCondition-detail)

Use something like that:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
if ($useC1)
{
    $criteria->addInCondition('c1', getOptionsArrayForC1());
}
if ($useC2)
{
    $criteria->addInCondition('c2', getOptionsArrayForC2());
}
if ($useC3)
{
    $criteria->addInCondition('c3', getOptionsArrayForC3());
}
```